# Auto-Capitalize Variable in IntelliJ Live Templates

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14, live-templates

(Note: This question is in regards to IntelliJ 14. Older or newer versions might not have the menus mentioned here.)

I'm trying to set up a live template that allows me to type a constant in **all caps**.

So, if the normal syntax is *Titles.PAGETITLE*, and I create a live template that expands **pt** into *Titles.$PAGETITLE$*, the result should be *Titles.* appearing on the line with my cursor placed after the period.

It's here that I want whatever I type to be inserted in all capitalized letters, without using Caps Lock or Shift. My lowercase input should be converted to uppercase input.

I've tried using the *Expression* option in the *Edit Template Variables* dialog with the following:

- The pre-defined **capitalize(String)** function
- A custom-written **(String).toUpperCase()** function
- A custom-written **Var.toUpperCase()** function
- A couple other things I can't recall off the top of my head...

A more specific example of what I'm trying to accomplish is actually a custom JSP tag, as seen below.

```
<TAG:type property="<%=Titles.PAGETITLE%>" />
```

So if I type the template name on a line and expand it (with 'Tab', in my case):

```
tagtitle
```

Then the following should appear (pipe for cursor position):

```
<TAG:type property="<%=Titles.|%>" />
```

And as I type *pagetitle*, it should appear in caps like so:

```
<TAG:type property="<%=Titles.PAGETITLE%>" />
```

How do I accomplish this from within the defined live template?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature in IntelliJ IDEA, either in version 14 or in a later version (2016.2 is the latest as of this writing). Expressions in live templates can be used to calculate the value of one variable in a template based on the value of another variable, after the other variable has been entered. They cannot be used to update the value of a variable as you type it.